# Angular2 HTTP Get Observable - How to wait for result

Tags: arrays, angular

I am trying to validate a user token by the means of a back-end API.  I am brand new to Angular2 in general.  My question is, if I want isValidToken to return a boolean value of whether or not the token provided was valid, how can I wait for the HTTP call to complete prior to return in result from isValidToken()?

```
isValidToken(token: string): boolean {
    var isValidToken: boolean = false;
    this.getIsValidToken(token).subscribe(
        data => {
            isValidToken = data.isValidToken;
            return isValidToken;
        },
        error => {
            return false;
        }
    );
}

getIsValidToken(token: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.validateTokenUrl + '?tokenString=' + token)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isValidToken` needs to return `Observable<boolean>` or `Promise<boolean>`. It can't return the value synchronously because it relies on an asynchronous method for it's result.

It's turtles all the way down.

Comment: Yea, I've been reading that all over. Can you give an example though on how I can use the returned value in another method?

Answer (score 0):

```
isValidToken(token: string): boolean {
    return this.getIsValidToken(token);
}

getIsValidToken(token: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.validateTokenUrl + '?tokenString=' + token)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

then you can use it like

```
someMethod() {
  this.isValidToken.subscribe(token => {
    if(token) {
      this.success = true;
      // or some other code that should be executed when `token` is `true`
    } else {
      this.success = false;
      // or some other code that should be executed when `token` is `false`
    }
  },
  error => {
      this.success = false;
      // or some other code that should be executed when `token` is `false`
  });
}
```

You can't go to sync execution from an async call. All you can do is return the observable (or promise) for the caller to be able to subscribe and register a callback to be called when data events are emitted or errors occur.